# base cases for recursive functions

Tags: python, recursion

What would be a possible base case for a recursive function that takes in any integer p and a non-negative integer j. the function should return the result when 11 is subtracted from the number j repeatedly n times.

I have my attempts below but am not sure if they are correct.

```
def subtract(p,j):
    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError ('Eexpecting non-negative n')
    if x == 11 and n == 0:
        return 11
    while n >= 0:
        x = x-11
        n-=1
    return x
```

Comment: That function is not recursive. A recursive function is one that calls itself.

Answer (score 0):

The function that you have posted isn't a [recursive function](https://techterms.com/definition/recursivefunction) and you don't one. The definition of the recursive function says:

> A recursive function is a function that calls itself during its execution.

Try this:

```
def sub_eleven(x, n):
    return x - n * 11
```

However, if you have some reason to implement it using recursion, try this:

```
def sub_eleven(x, n):
    if n <= 0: # Base Condition
        return x
    return sub_eleven(x - 11, n - 1) # Calling itself with different arguments/state
```